# Python - Cant make it to encode string properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, character-encoding, beautifulsoup

Im trying to grab some data and here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.privredni-imenik.com/firma/68225-a_expo'
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"podaci"})
for i in g_data:
    some = i.text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
    print (some)
```

It works, however the results looks like this:

```
b'A & L EXPO PREDUZE\xc4\x86E ZA PROIZVODNJU
```

Where `\xc4\x86` should be represented with letter `Ć`.

How can i make it to work?

Comment: why not just print the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a string, just print the text:

```
In [18]: g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"podaci"})

In [19]: for i in g_data:
   ....:         some = i.text
   ....:         print (some)
   ....:     
A & L EXPO PREDUZEĆE ZA PROIZVODNJU, TRGOVINU I USLUGE DOO 11070 BEOGRAD VLADIMIRA POPOVTelefaksMatični broj: 17461460  Informacije o delatnostima koje obavlja ova firma:  » Organizovanje sastanaka i sajmova 

In [20]:  print(type(some))
<class 'str'>    
In [21]: print(type(some.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')))
<class 'bytes'>
```

You are encoding  to `bytes` with `i.text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')` there is no need to do anything at all bar print the text.

Comment: If i want to print just text, then i receive error: 
`File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0106' in position 18: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: What is your editor of choice? Im using PyCharm and somehow managed to set file encoding. Now is ok, but console is returning me just one part of the string...

Comment: What is your locale set to in cmd?

Comment: Same. for some reason it is returning just one part of the string. Its not important anymore.. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

`b'\xc4\x86'` is a bytes object, not string (you can tell by the 'b' in front of the quotation mark). Therefore, any characters outside of the limited ascii set are going to be displayed by their hex representation if you try printing the bytes object. To print the utf-8 characters that you want to see, you need to decode the bytes object to a string object (or, looking at your code, just not encode it into a bytes object in the first place).

For example, try:

```
>>> b'\xc4\x86'.decode()
'Ć'
```

For more information read about bytes and strings here:
http://www.diveintopython3.net/strings.html